# timezone in openair aggregate

Tags: r, timezone, aggregate, openair

As a R learner, I'm using "timeAverage" function in the "openair" package to aggregate my hourly data into daily basis. My data is in EST timezone, and I would like to have my results in EST timezone as well.

This is the code I use, pretty simple:
require(openair)
daily <- timeAverage(comparison,avg.time="day")

However, I encountered a warning message:
**Warning message:
In checkPrep(mydata, vars, type = "default", remove.calm = FALSE,  :
  Detected data with Daylight Saving Time, converting to UTC/GMT**

Is this means my output is in GMT timezone? How can I keep my timezone as EST in the output?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you actually mean EST (fixed to UTC-5), or do you mean the North American Eastern time zone (UTC-5 in the winter and UTC-4 in the summer) ?

Comment: There is a discussion of timezones in the [June 2014 openair News](http://www.openair-project.org/PDF/OpenAir_NewsLetter_Issue16.pdf). See "More robust handling of date-times" on pages 5-6. Hope this helps.